# Finding the maximum sum we can get by inserting some numbers into a sequence

Tags: algorithms

We have a sequence of integers: $x_1 , x_2, \dots , x_n$, of which only $x_1$ and $x_n$ are given. We are also given an integer $d$. How do we compute the maximum sum $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n$ such that the absolute difference between any $2$ *consecutive* elements is at most $d$?

Answer (score 0):

$$ \text {In addition to } x_1 \text {, } x_n \text { and d, you also need to know n.}$$
$$ \text {I will take the case where }x_n \ge x_1 \ge 0, d > 0 \text { and } n > 2.$$
$$ \text {You can do the same for } x_1 > x_n \text { too by reversing the operations.}$$
$$ \text {The idea is to start from } x_1 \text { and keep adding d such that } x_{m+1} = x_1 + m.d$$
$$ \text {Then for the rest of the series, take } x_n$$
$$\text { and start going from right (n) to left (till m+2) by adding d.}$$
$$ \text {So, } x_{m+2} = x_n + (n-m-2).d$$
$$ \text {For maximum sum of the sequence of integers with }$$
$$|x_{m+1} - x_{m+2}| \le d \text {, equate } x_{m+1} \text { and } x_{m+2}$$

$$\text { that gives, } m = \frac{(x_n-x_1)+(n-2).d}{2d}$$
Key part is to round off fraction to 0 or 1 (0.5 or greater is 1).

Once you know m, it is simple.

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{m+1} x_i = (m+1).x_1 + \frac {m.(m+1)}{2}.d$$
$$ \sum_{i=m+2}^{n} x_i = (n-m-1).x_n + \frac{(n-m-2)(n-m-1)}{2}.d$$
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \sum_{i=1}^{m+1} x_i + \sum_{i=m+2}^{n} x_i $$